# Material design light mdl-select

Tags: angularjs, material-design-lite

I'm trying to use the mdl-select component in an Angular app.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <mdl-select formControlName="personId">
    <mdl-option *ngFor="let p of people" [value]="p.id">{{p.name}}</mdl-option>
  </mdl-select>
</form>
```

I installed using the instructions from here: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/tree/master/src/components/select

Getting this console error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'mdl-option'.
1. If 'mdl-option' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mdl-option' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("tiple="true" placeholder="Select users">
        <mdl-option mdl-ripple *ngFor="let hero of heroes" [ERROR ->][value]="hero.name">{{hero.name}}</mdl-option>
      </mdl-select>

"): ng:///AppModule/NewEventComponent.html@19:59
```

Comment: What do your imports look like? Whenever I've run into this it's been an import or bootstrapping issue

Comment: Just like the instructions from here. https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/tree/master/src/components/select. I used the `import { MdlSelectModule } from '@angular-mdl/select';` in the component where I need the select.

Comment: can you try `import { MdlOptionComponent } from '@angular-mdl/option';` as well?

Comment: Cannot find module '@angular-mdl/option'. I even tried installing it but got this `npm ERR! 404 Not found : @angular-mdl/option`. Even if I comment the `mdl-option` from the html, I get `mdl-select' is not a known element:`

Comment: Ahh I just looked at their code base again .. try this:

`import { MdlSelectModule, MdlOptionComponent } from '@angular-mdl/select';`

Comment: Nope ... still doesn't like mdl-option `Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'mdl-option'.
1. If 'mdl-option' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.` ... but I think I'm using this wrong.

Comment: Ok I've got one more idea.. Can you actually import these in your app.module.ts, and then include the `MdlOptionComponent` in your `declarations` array, and the `MdlSelectModule` into your `imports` array? After that you'd want to remove the imports from your component that is using the Components

Comment: Uncaught Error: Type MdlOptionComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: MdlSelectModule and AppModule! Please consider moving MdlOptionComponent to a higher module that imports MdlSelectModule and AppModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes MdlOptionComponent then import that NgModule in MdlSelectModule and AppModule.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! OptionComponent is already imported by the Select. If you remove the import and declaration of Option in `app.module.ts` and leave the `MdlSelectModule`, you might be in luck

Comment: Yeah. That was it. Still have an error, but that's because I copy pasted the example from GitHub. Add an answer please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you aren't importing the module property, as it needs to be bootstrapped in your root `app.module.ts`.

Take the `import { MdlSelectModule } from '@angular-mdl/option'` out of your custom component, and move it to `app.module.ts`. Additionally, add `MdlSelectModule` to your `imports: []` array in `app.module.ts`